# Open kickoff via shell/script

Tags: scripting, kde, d-bus, kde4

Is there any (undocumented) way to open the KDE Kickoff menu via dbus or some similar mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a thread on the [KDE forums](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=8738&incap_redirect=2) but it doesn't seem to work (and I had to modify the command a bit: `qdbus org.kde.plasma-desktop /kickoff`)

Another approach would be to fake a key event:

- right click on the K, click on 'Application Launcher Settings' and then set a shortcut (if Alt+F1 doesn't work right away)
- install xdotool
- run `xdotool keydown keydown --delay 200 alt key F1 keyup alt`

It seems that you need to have a little delay between the alt and the F1 keys (hence the `--delay`). I first tried it with 100ms but it didn't always work. 200ms seem to be enough though (at least for my system).

Comment: That's one hell of a hack, but since my goal is to have a panel-less keybinding I just go with that. Thanks! :)