# Command to open application dashboard?

Tags: kde, xmonad, kde5

I'm using KDE 5 with xmonad. I'm trying to map mod+shift+p to open the Application Dashboard (full-screen application launcher), but I can't figure out how I would launch it with a command.

Comment: What's the "Application Dashboard (full-screen application launcher)"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spawn function. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.13/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:spawn

You would need to determine the command to launch the application dashboard.

Example: `spawn firefox`.

Comment: I know spawn, but as I said in the question, "I can't figure out how I would launch it [the Dashboard] with a command"

Comment: The actual application launcher might have a name. Possibly it's kickoff: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64324/open-kickoff-via-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

***mod+shift+p*** in default config spawns `gmrun`.

***mod+p*** spawns `dmenu`.

you can override this with own keybinding and spawn funcion on this keys.
More useful info about keybindigs is on [General tips for configuring XMonad](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/General_xmonad.hs_config_tips#Key_and_Mouse_Bindings)